# Why won't this bootstrap modal display properly in flexslider 2.2?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I feel as if it's right in front of my face...

I'm trying to get modals to load within flex slider.

- [Example 1 with flex slider 2.2](http://jsfiddle.net/W39AC/15/)
- [Example 2 with flex slider 2.0](http://jsfiddle.net/W39AC/16/)

The modal loads correctly with flex slider 2.0 but not 2.2 and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it work properly with flexslider 2.2

any ideas?

*I had a really hard time trying to embed html into the question... -_-

Answer (score 0):

Can't figure out why, but it's z-index issue. This is corrected though:

### DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/B6FKE/

CSS

```
 html > body.modal-open.flex-open > div.modal-backdrop.fade.in {z-index:1;}
```

JS

```
 $(window).load(function() {

   $(".flexslider .slides .btn").click(function () {
     $('body').addClass('flex-open');
   });

$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    controlNav: false,
    slideshow: false
 });

}); // end
```